Turn it into a city
Move exactly 2 matchsticks to turn this number into a city


Can it be literally any city or only capitals?

Are abbreviations allowed?

Full name of a popular city.

Popular is very subjective, I can make another city with more population than the accepted answer (namely rot13(Bab, va Wncna)) by moving 2 matchsticks.

@Fluorine You could post that as an answer.

@Fluorine: Wouldn’t that be by moving only one matchstick?

@PierrePaquette no. I posted my answer if you want to check how to do it in two.

You can move two matchsticks to make the name of the city...

 APIA, the capital of Samoa.

Like so:

 

 Remove the two lowest horizontal matchsticks, move the right-hand one halfway up, and position the other across the top of the central two uprights to make a Greek letter π symbol, giving us the letters PI (via the lateral-thinking tag) in between two A's!


I've been to that city and I wouldn't consider it a popular city or a well known one at all.

@KateGregory I think definitions of 'popular' will vary from person to person - as a quiz enthusiast I would personally consider any capital city fair game, but I'm very aware others might think the smaller ones shouldn't be counted in the same breath as places the size of Tokyo, Paris or London. (PS The OP's comment you reference actually had no bearing on my answer, which was posted just before it!)

Since there's been doubt here is my solution:

 ONO, a city in Japan with a population of 47,609 in April 2022 compared to 35,974 for Apia (2021). In that sense, it is a more popular city.

And yes, you can do it by moving exactly two matchsticks:

 


 I guess since it is not obvious to use a matchstick to replace another one it kind of satisfies the lateral thinking tag. I have no doubt this is not the intended solution, but it shows that multiple solutions were possible.


Apia is a capital, which makes it more popular imho.

@FlorianF sure, but that's not the point, nor does it bring anything to say that. It's merely to show the speculative aspect, which later got the question closed (until that's cleared). Actually the use of imho in your comment points out the speculative aspect even more.

The point is you are mixing up "populous" and "popular".  The population is besides the point.  I have never heard of Ono but I have heard of Apia, so Apia is more popular imho.

@FlorianF guess what, the population is a good indicator of how popular a city is. And I'm pretty sure that a lot of people have heard of Ono, particularly in Japan, don't be obtuse please. Saying the population is besides the point is totally up to your interpretation, which is fine, but again you are missing the point.

This is what I got:

白山


One of the first things that came to my mind when seeing the initial setup was Chinese characters. If you move only 2 matches (with perhaps a little slight resizing to help it look better), you get the Chinese city, 白山, Baishan (roughly pronounced buy-shawn).


 

